# Python/Numpy array dimension confusion

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose `batch_size = 64`.
I created a batch : `batch = np.zeros((self._batch_size,), dtype=np.int64)`. Suppose I have batch of chars such that `batch = ['o', 'w', ....'s']` of 64 size and `'o'` will be represented as `[0,0, .... 0]` 1-hot vector of size 27.
So, is there any way such that batch will still have shape of batch_size and not batch_size x vocabulary_size?
Code is as follows :

```
batch = np.zeros((self._batch_size,), dtype=np.int64)  
temp1 = list()
for b in range(self._batch_size):
  temp = np.zeros(shape=(vocabulary_size), dtype=np.int64)
  temp[char2id(self._text[self._cursor[b]])] = 1.0
  temp1.append(temp)
  self._cursor[b] = (self._cursor[b] + 1) % self._text_size
batch = np.asarray(list)
return batch
```

This return batch as dimension of batch_size x vocabulary_size.

```
batch = np.zeros((self._batch_size,), dtype=np.int64)  
for b in range(self._batch_size):
  batch[b, char2id(self._text[self._cursor[b]])] = 1.0
  self._cursor[b] = (self._cursor[b] + 1) % self._text_size
return batch
```

This code returns an error of too many few indices.
Is there any way of specifying array size as `[batch_size :, None]`?

Comment: How do you expect it to represent 27 values (0 and 1) for 64 'batches'?  What do you intend to do with the array once it's created?

Answer (score 1):

In the 1st block the initialization of `batch` to `zeros` does nothing for you, because `batch` is replaced with the `asarray(temp1)` later. (Note my correction).  `temp1` is a list of 1d arrays (`temp`), and produces a 2d arrray.

In the 2nd if you start with `batch=np.zeros((batch_size, vocab_size))` you would avoid the index number error.

You can't use `None` instead of a real integer.  `None` does not work like a broadcasting `newaxis` here. Arrays don't grow by assigning a new larger index.  Even when used in indexing `np.zeros((batchsize,))[:,None]` the result is 2d, shape (batchsize,1).

Why do you want a 1d array?  It's possible to construct a 1d array of dtype object that contains arrays (or any other object), but for many purposes it is just a glorified list.

Comment: I needed it for function embedded_lookup() in tensorflow. Input should be of dimension (batch_size,).How to construct 1d array of dtype object that contains which you were about to mention?